# Regex remove eveything between <description> tag except image tag

Tags: regex, drupal-7, feed

I'm parsing data in drupal from RSS. i want to remove everything between  tag except image tag

```
<description><![CDATA[
<img src="myimageurl.jpg" alt="" />


   <p>By Lambert, Kenneth and Juneja, B.L.. 
   New Delhi : Cengage, 2015
                    . 394p.


                     9788131529034
   </p>
```

[Place Hold on *Fundamentals of Python*](/cgi-bin/koha/opac-reserve.pl?biblionumber=2172)

```
                    </description>
```

i want my output as

`<description>
<img src="http://images.amazon.com/images/P/8131529037.01.TZZZZZZZ.jpg"/>
</description>`

Answer (score 0):

You can instead fetch `img` tag only and surround it with `<description>` tag.

Regex to get `<img>` tag:

```
<img.*\/>
```